# Rendering the Euro Symbol in Google Charts

Tags: html, google-visualization, euro

Google Charts has a dichotomy between formatters in the data table and in the views. I have successfully formatted my data table to have a Euro Symbol, but it does not render the same in the views. In the table, I can use NumberFormatter and everything that comes with it. In the views, I can only use a ICU-based pattern format.

I've tried copying the Euro Symbol from various web sources and using various encodings (HTML UTF-8, etc.) and nothing has worked. The encodings are just printed to screen.

I see the symbol passed correctly from my database through the Java.

Also, it works for both data table and views for the UK Pound Sterling.

Any advice?